# Can I replace a binary treatment variable with a continuous treatment variable after matching

Tags: regression, matching

I have a continuous treatment variable which I dichtomize into a binary treatment dummy. Using MatchIt and the newly created dummy variable, I conducted genetic matching to create a dataset of treatment and control observations. My question is, can I replace that binary treatment variable with the original continuous treatment variable in a subsequent OLS regression analysis? If so are there any additional steps I must take, such adjusting standard errors or weighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never dichotomize a continuous treatment, especially when methods exist for adjusting for confounding with continuous treatments. Dichotomizing and then matching will fail to make treatment independent from the covariates, which is the whole point of matching. Just use a method that is well-suited for continuous treatments. `WeightIt` offers many options for weighting for continuous treatments. The `cobalt` [vignette](https://ngreifer.github.io/cobalt/articles/cobalt.html#using-cobalt-with-continuous-treatments) provides guidance on assessing balance for continuous treatments, and the `WeightIt` [vignette](https://ngreifer.github.io/WeightIt/articles/estimating-effects.html#continuous-treatments) on estimating effects provides guidance on estimating the average dose-response function of a continuous treatment.

Weighting methods for continuous treatments aim to make the treatment independent of the covariates in the weighted sample. There are version that involve modeling the treatment and using methodology similar to propensity score weighting, but colleagues and I recently developed a powerful method that doesn't require modeling the treatment called distance covariance optimal weights, which you can read about in [Huling et al. (2023)](https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.2023.2213485) and which are implemented in `WeightIt` by using `weightit()` with `method = "energy"`.